# Update field in rendered Django Form

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, forms

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to update a Field in Django Form while editing the Form.

In my form I have a ModelChoiceField and ChoiceField: first is a list of Car manufacturers, second is a list of models available for this manufacturer. Obviously I don't want to fill second field with models for every manufacturer but only for one selected in first ModelChoiceField.

Here's my example Form:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    make = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Manufacturer.objects.all())
    model = forms.ChoiceField()
    ...
```

To render the template with form I use Class-based View:

```
class CreatePost(View):
    template_name = 'post/edit_post.html'

def get(self, request):
    form = PostForm()
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

def post(self, request):
    form = PostForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.owner = request.user
        post.save()
        return redirect('homepage')

    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

In my template after I render `PostForm` I disable `model` field with `jQuery` and wait for user to select some value in `make` field. Here's my template:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.non_field_errors }}
      {% for field in form %}
           <div class="form-group">
             <label class="control-label">{{ field.label_tag }}</label>
             {{ field }}
             {{ field.errors }}
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
           </div>
      {% endfor %}      
</form>
```

And then use `AJAX` to request values for `model` field (in this sample code I only return single item):

```
$('#id_make').change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '{% url 'get_models' %}',
            data: {'make': $('#id_make :selected').text()},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#id_model').append($('<option>', {
                    value: 1,
                    text: data.model})).removeAttr('disabled');
                }
            });
        })
```

Here's the view I'm using to process AJAX call (for display purposes and to keep things simple in this question I have only one record in `models` table `Series` for each `manufacturer` and knowing this I only query for one record. `series` is CharField that keeps title of `model` like 'Lancer' for 'Mitsubishi' manufacturer.):

```
def get_models(request):
    manufacturer = Manufacturer.objects.get(make=request.GET.get('make'))
    model = Series.objects.get(make_fk= manufacturer)
    return JsonResponse({'model': model.series})
```

With this done I do see updated options in `<select>` element for `model ChoiceField`, but after I select new value in `model ChoiceField` and submit form I receive:

```
Select a valid choice. 1 is not one of the available choices."
```

- '1' is id of the element that I appended to `<select>` element and then submit.

I then dug deeper and printed the contents of submitted Form and it appeared that although I saw `<select>` element updated in the template, it stayed blank in the Form I've submitted:

```
<select name="model" class="form-control" id="id_model"></select>
```

Why is this happening and how to update Form fields itself rather than just `<select>` element?

Comment: Can you please share your template form code?

Comment: @TheCoder did as you asked

Comment: hmm.. thanks! could you please add also the view part code?

Comment: @TheCoder added view for AJAX call, would you also like to see View Class that renders the template? It's pretty standard.

Comment: Yes, sharing View Class code would be helpful!

Comment: @TheCoder I've added Template View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found explained solution with code examples how to implement chained/dependent dropdowns, coincidentally the solution was posted literally right after I posted this question.

[Here's a link.](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html)

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, you haven't set any choices of `model`, so it will never be valid. You could override the `__init__` method and set the choices there.

You could set the choices to be all models, and then in the `clean` method verify that the model matches the make.

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    make = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Manufacturer.objects.all())
    model = forms.ChoiceField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.data:
            self.fields['model'].choices = ...

    def clean(self)
        # check that model matches make
```

Since the `model` field refers to the `series` model, it might be easier to use a `ModelChoiceField` and set `self.fields['model'].queryset` instead.

This was just a rough idea off the top of my head. The [tutorial you found](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html) uses a similar approach but is complete and explained in more detail.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but if I understand your answer correctly you're suggesting to populate the "ChoiceField" with all models for all manufacturers and then check if user selected matching make and model in clean() method? Please correct me if that's not what you've meant but if it is - that is exactly kind of flow I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Or what you mean is load all models for all makers to "ModelChoiceField", hide everything once the template loaded and populate the <select> element as before with Ajax request from scratch, only this time every model I potentially will assign to <option> will already be in Form I initially passed to template? This actually might work...

Comment: The key point is that you only populate the choices for the POST request (when `self.data` evaluates to `True`). For the initial `GET` request, the choices are still empty and populated in the template using ajax. The tutorial you linked to takes the same approach, but it filters the queryset in the `__init__` method, so the `clean` isn't required. The suggestion to use `ModelChoiceField()` is completely separate